# download csv using spring boot and apache commons

Tags: spring-boot, export-to-csv, apache-commons

I have this below code for downloading CSV as an ajax button click, But the file is not downloading. Only showing the black new tab on the browser.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/batch/download", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/csv")
     @ResponseBody
     public void downloadNGIBatchSelected(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
         List<String> ids = Arrays.asList("1312321","312313");

         generateNewCustomerCSV(response.getWriter(),ids);
     }

     private void generateNewCustomerCSV(PrintWriter writer, List<String> ids){
     String NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR = "\n";
       //CSV file header
       Object[] FILE_HEADER = {"Token Number",
               "Token Expiry Date",

          };
       CSVPrinter csvPrinter = null;
       try {
           csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(new BufferedWriter(writer), CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withRecordSeparator(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR));
           //Create CSV file header
           csvPrinter.printRecord(FILE_HEADER);

           for (PolicyMap PolicyMap : policyMaps) {
               List customerCSV = new ArrayList();
               customerCSV.add(PolicyMap.getInsurancePolicy().getTokenNo());
             try {
                   csvPrinter.printRecord(customerCSV);
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } finally {
           try {
               writer.flush();
               writer.close();
               csvPrinter.close();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               System.out.println("Error while flushing/closing fileWriter/csvPrinter !!!");
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 6):

You have set the content type in `@RequestMapping` annotation. But it is not going to work in the case when response is being written using `HttpServletResponse`. In this case, instead of spring, `HttpServletResponse` is writing the response that's why you have to set the response type in the response before getting the writer.

```
response.setContentType ("application/csv");
response.setHeader ("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"nishith.csv\"");
```

Comment: Content-type is not necessary.